# How can I plot data on the globe using Mayavi?

Tags: python, netcdf4, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I wanted to plot the Indian ocean data on a globe. I am not able to get the proper positioning of the plot. https://github.com/rajivjha0599/cdf is the link to cdf file i've been working with. Another problem is that I am not able to plot all the points and the window crashes without completing the plotting and i'm only able to plot 100 points.

```
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
from mayavi.sources.builtin_surface import BuiltinSurface
import xarray as xr
dataset = xr.open_dataset('indian_ocean.nc', decode_times=False)

# Extract latitude, longitude, and temperature data
latitude = dataset['LAT64_1376'].values
longitude = dataset['LON2501_3751'].values
temperature = dataset['WATER_TEMP'].values[0, 0, :, :]

mlab.figure(1, bgcolor=(0.48, 0.48, 0.48), fgcolor=(0, 0, 0),
               size=(400, 400))
continents_src = BuiltinSurface(source='earth', name='Continents')
continents_src.data_source.on_ratio = 1
continents = mlab.pipeline.surface(continents_src, color=(0, 0, 0))
sphere = mlab.points3d(0, 0, 0, scale_mode='none',
                                scale_factor=2,
                                color=(0.67, 0.77, 0.93),
                                resolution=50,
                                opacity=0.7,
                                name='Earth')
# These parameters, as well as the color, where tweaked through the GUI,
# with the record mode to produce lines of code usable in a script.
sphere.actor.property.specular = 0.45
sphere.actor.property.specular_power = 5
# Backface culling is necessary for more a beautiful transparent
# rendering.
sphere.actor.property.backface_culling = True

theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)

for angle in (- np.pi / 6, 0, np.pi / 6):
    x = np.cos(theta) * np.cos(angle)
    y = np.sin(theta) * np.cos(angle)
    z = np.ones_like(theta) * np.sin(angle)

    mlab.plot3d(x, y, z, color=(1, 1, 1),
                        opacity=0.2, tube_radius=None)

mlab.view(63.4, 73.8, 4, [-0.05, 0, 0])
########################################################
#######################################################################

test=[]
for lat in latitude:
    for long in longitude:
       x = np.cos(long* np.pi / 180) * np.cos(lat* np.pi / 180)
       y = np.cos(long* np.pi / 180) * np.sin(lat* np.pi / 180)
       z = np.sin(long* np.pi / 180) 
       test.append([x,y,z]) 
       print(len(test))
       #points = mlab.points3d(x, y, z,scale_mode='none',scale_factor=0.03,color=(0, 0, 1))
for element in test[1:100]:
    points = mlab.points3d(element[0], element[1], element[2],scale_mode='none',scale_factor=0.03,color=(0, 0, 1))
#######################################################################
######################################################
mlab.show()
```